# Always On Availability Groups with Encrypted Connections

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, encryption, connections

We have a two-node SQL Server 2016 AOAG, TestA, TestB and listener TestL. We want to begin using encrypted connections between the app server/client and the db server.

I have found the section below in two MS documents about implementing connection encrypting. Just wanted to know if this holds true for AOAGs? I suspect it does since AOAG does require the use of a failover cluster, but would like confirmation.

> **Encryption on a Cluster**
>
> If you want to use encryption with a failover cluster, you must install the server certificate with the fully qualified DNS name of the failover clustered instance on all nodes in the failover cluster. For example, if you have a two-node cluster, with nodes named test1.your company.com and test2. your company.com and a failover clustered instance of SQL Server named fcisql, you must obtain a certificate for fcisql.your company.com and install the certificate on both nodes. To configure the failover cluster for encryption, you can then select the ForceEncryption check box on the Protocols for  property box of SQL Server Network Configuration

Answer (score 6):

First for an AG you need to Force Protocol Encryption on each instance participating in the AG.  With an FCI there is only one instance.

Also with an AG clients can connect to the AG Listener, and they can connect to the instances directly.  So you have to configure the certificates accordingly.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover#SSLcertificates

Note, that this configuration is not *required* to have protocol encryption.  It's required to authenticate the SQL Server to the clients.  If you merely want protocol encryption, clients may always request it, or you can force it on the server with a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach you may want to look into (if you're only looking to encrypt a subset of the data) is [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine).  It comes with all editions of SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later (or Enterprise Edition of SQL 2016 prior to SP1) and provides end-to-end encryption on a column level.  It is also compatible with Availability Groups, though there are other [limitations you should be aware of](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-69-always-encrypted-limitations/).

While SSL encrypts data in transit, it doesn't encrypt the data at rest.  Forcing SSL connections and enabling [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde) can emulate a similar level of security as Always Encrypted, but at the database level instead.  These two features though will not encrypt the data in memory, whereas Always Encrypted does this because data is decrypted at the client.

Finally, TDE is a feature that is exclusive to Enterprise Edition on versions older than SQL Server 2019. On SQL Server 2019 and above, you are able to apply TDE encryption on Standard edition instances. See the differences and supported features between editions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15#RDBMSS). Be aware of the licensing requirements if you decide to go further down the encryption rabbit hole.